# Chart js. Как переделать код с jquery на angular, чтобы передать данные для построения графиков

Tags: angularjs, chart.js

Передаю данные для построения графиков при помощи выпадающего списка. Код написан на jQuery. Как переписать этот код на Angular 1.5?

Пример и весь код здесь https://plnkr.co/edit/NR7GKcyqdjJKBfWB5fTG?p=preview

**html**

```
<select id="test">
<option isabled selected value="">Choose options</option>
<option value="kpi_2">Kpi 2</option>
<option value="kpi_3">Kpi 3</option>
```

**js**

```
var dataFee = {
        labels: [],
        datasets: [{
            label: " ",
            data: [18, 16, 125, 65, 100, 71, 12],
            ....
        }],

    };

    var ctx = $("#myChartLine").get(0).getContext("2d");
    var myLineChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: "line",
        data: dataFee,
    });

$('#test').change(function(){
  const val = $(this).val();

    switch (val){
        case 'kpi_2':

        var secondData = {
            label: " ",
            data: [1, 12, 115, 55, 90, 80, 22],
            .....
        };

            dataFee.datasets.push(secondData);
            myLineChart.update();

        break;
        ...
    }

});
```

Comment: Покажите, как далеко продвинулись в переделывании на `angular`?

Comment: Думаю, что не продвинулся. Здесь у меня как раз и ступор. Не знаю как переписать вот эту функцию  $('#test').change(function(){
    const val = $(this).val();

Comment: Здесь начал делать на angular https://plnkr.co/edit/McPMClaYkhaISXJw8UjY?p=preview Думаю наверное как то так должно быть function createChart () {
     $scope.data = [];
     for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    $scope.data.push([{
      
      
    }]);
     }
   }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы были на верном пути и почти сделали.

Посмотрите готовый пример.

Пример на [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/WR3HZwtdN9UfJN792aws?p=preview).

```js
angular.module('app', ['chart.js'])
  .controller('LineCtrl', function() {

    var vm = this;

    vm.labelsMulty = ['w01', 'w02', 'w03', 'w04', 'w05', 'w06', 'w07'];
    vm.seriesMulty = [];
    vm.dataMulty = [];

    vm.kpis = [{
      name: 'kpi 1',
      value: 'kpi_1',
      data: [12, 45, 77, 11, 75, 57, 50]
    }, {
      name: 'kpi 2',
      value: 'kpi_2',
      data: [75, 57, 75, 57, 8, 54, 54]
    }, {
      name: 'kpi 3',
      value: 'kpi_3',
      data: [54, 35, 35, 53, 24, 54, 75]
    }];
    vm.change = change;

    function change() {
      if (!vm.myKpi)
        return;
      if (vm.seriesMulty.indexOf(vm.myKpi.name) > -1)
        return;
      vm.dataMulty.push(vm.myKpi.data);
      vm.seriesMulty.push(vm.myKpi.name);

    }

  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.6/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.4.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/angular.chartjs/latest/angular-chart.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="LineCtrl as vm">

    <div>
      <canvas class="chart chart-line" chart-data="vm.dataMulty" chart-labels="vm.labelsMulty" chart-series="vm.seriesMulty">
    </canvas>

    </div>

    <select ng-model="vm.myKpi" ng-options="kpi as kpi.name for kpi in vm.kpis" ng-change="vm.change()">
    <option value="">-- choose option --</option>
  </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо, за помощь!)